# Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/J$ is a domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Part 1: Prove that $J=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

1. $(0,0)\in J$ so nonempty
2. $(a,0)-(b,0)=(a-b,0)\in J$ so closed under subtraction
3. $(a,0)(b,0)=(ab,0)\in J$ so closed under multiplication

Therefore $J$ is a subring of $ \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

$(x,0)(a,b)=(xa,0)\in J$, so $J$ has the absorbtion property in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

---

Part 2: Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/J$ is a domain.

To show something is a domain, I have to show it has no zero divisors.

That is $(J+(a,b))(J+(c,d))\neq (J+(0,0))$.

But I'm not sure how to go about showing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you distribute the multiplication over the sums? $(J+(a,b))(J+(c,d)) = J^2 +(a,b)J+J(c,d)+(a,b)(c,d) = J+J+J+(a,b)(c,d)=... $

Comment: Show that $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/J\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @vinnief But isn't $J+J+J+(a,b)(c,d)=3J+(a,b)(c,d)=J+(a,b)(c,d)$?

Comment: Yes, and when is $J+(a,b)(a,d) = J+(0,0)$?

Comment: When either $a,b,c,d=0$ or $a=0 \text{ and} c \text{ or} d =0$ or $b=0 \text{ and} c \text { or} d =0$

Comment: It should have been $a=0$ and $b$ or $d=0$ or $c=0$ and $b$ or $d=0$. Because we get $J+(ac,bd)$

Comment: Ok, now use the definition of $J$: anything in $J$ looks like $(x,0)$, so $J+(ac,bd) = J+(0,bd)$ and also use the definition of zero in $\mathbb{Z}^2/J$: $J+(x,y)= J+(0,0)$ iff ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the map $(x,y)\mapsto y$ from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. This should solve your problem almost instantly.

Comment: Doesn't this also have zero divisors? $(2,0)(1,4)=(2,0)\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops This has *no* relevance. Is the map a ring homomorphism? If so, what consequences can you draw?

Comment: It is a ring homomorphism because addition and multiplication are preserved. I'm not sure what I can get from that though.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops If $f\colon R\to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, then it induces an isomorphism from $R/\ker f\to S$.